# need to send HTTP request based on the event

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

Below is the java script which send HTTP GET to URL (here google.com) periodically ( here 7 secs ). Now when the Java script is executed at a given interval i need to check if the user had performed the action ( like Mousedown, Mousemove etc ) and then only need to send the HTTP request.Please let me know the approach / solution.

```
    out.println("function bustOut(){");
    out.println("var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();");
    out.println("xhr.open(\"GET\",\"http://www.google.com\", true);");
    out.println("xhr.setRequestHeader(\"Content-Type\", \"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\");");
    // some where here i need to check for the event.For example - if user had performed the action (Mousedown, Mousemove etc ) then only send the HTTP request.
    out.println("xhr.send();");
    out.println("};");
    out.println("</script></head> ");
    out.println("<body onLoad=\"setInterval(function(){ bustOut();},7000);\"></body>");
```

These action ( like Mousedown, Mousemove etc ) will be performed on the browser

Comment: 'i need to check if the user had performed the action ( like Mousedown, Mousemove etc )' 
action on what,where? You need to be more precise with your question

Comment: The more detail you give the more help you will receive. Right now it seems like you have a partial idea of what you need. Can you provide more information?

Comment: @John, harsha : I don't have an idea of javascript.But these action will be performed on the browser.What other information you want? please let me know

Comment: Can you use jQuery? If yes, do so and use their eventlisteners. Check here for an example: http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

Comment: @Jakob: cant use jquery.I can use javascript in servlet.

Comment: You should be able to do the same thing with "normal" javascript, google eventlisteners and you should be able to find what you seek.

Comment: Yeah..i have searched on net but i am not getting how to fit in the above code.